# Is Scrum for Team System a good tool for managing the scrum process?

Tags: tfs, scrum

We've had several sprints with the traditional whiteboard and PostIt notes and are ready to move forward to integrating the process into our Team System environment. One tool we're considering is Conchango's "Scrum for Team System" (http://www.scrumforteamsystem.com/en/)

Has anyone tried this tool in a real world scrum process? Was your experience positive or negative? Is the tool worth the licensing fee in your opinion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use Scrum For Team System and love it.  It really does a good job of merging the TFS and Scrum processes.

We also got the task board (the part  you have to pay for) and really like that too.

Even with Scrum for Team System, TFS via visual studio is not good for planning meetings (though it is ok for standups)  The task board helps a lot in visualizing the work remaining and in moving it around.

Before we got the Task Board, we would use post it notes for our planning meetings and then enter them in to TFS after.  And even though the Task Board is nice, if you don't have at least 2 people working on it in a planning meeting then it is not enough.  We have 3 laptops going for a team of 5 + 1 (scrum master) and that works great.  If you don't have that then I would still think about doing post it notes.

The task board allows you to refresh and see what the other are entering in.  We have one computer hooked up to a projector so that the others can see what is happening.  We all then brainstorm like we would on post it notes, but the people on laptops enter the data into TFS.

For us, it works great!

Later Note: If you do choose the Scrum For Team System template then I STRONGLY recommend that you read the Process Guidance.  We had to figure out a few thing the hard way before we sat down and read it.  Especially on how to handle defects (i.e. when is it a Bug and when it is a Sprint Back Log Item that goes back to "In Progress")

Answer (score 2):

The templates are free.  It is only the Task Board Application that cost a modest fee.  You can use the templates without the Task Board although I highly recommend using it as wll.  I think the biggest advantage for my team has been that the ScrumForTeamSystem tempaltes integrate into VS and provide a seamless feel with the rest of the development environment.

We love the ability to attach the PBI's to check-ins and have them show up on the Daily Build report.

If you are are missing something you need, you can fire up the VS template editortweak the templates to your liking.  For us, we added a "Requested By" field and a "Testing Status" field to the PBI template.

The 2 shortcommings that annoyed us were that the "State" of the PBI's were not the same as SBI's (No Ready For Test on the PBI).  We do testing/validation at the feature level and not the task level and wanted to track the PBIs status so we had to add our own custom field.  The second issue was that there is no report out-of-the-box for a PBI burndown/up at the Sprint level.  So you can't see how you are doing at delivering stories, only tasks.  You have to make your own.

We don't really use the "Bug" template much (we ship flawless code:) ).  No really, there is no such thing as a bug against work in a sprint; so the only time we record a bug is if a client finds an issue in the production code where it didn't work as advertised.

As Vaccano said, it isn't nearly as fast as a whiteboard or post-its in a meeting environment but if you get a couple people really good at using the tool and a couple of laptops you can make it work.

I evaluated several products and the simplicity and price of ScrumForTeamSystem can't be beat.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, beware that the Conchango template handles bugs very differently.  The idea that unreleased Backlog Items are bug-free is not just a suggestion; there is literally **no way** to track bugs affecting the current sprint's work.  I found that this disadvantage outweighed the advantages.

Comment: The idea (as I understand it) is that if it is an issue in the current sprint then the task associated goes back to in progress and gets worked on.  If it is not associated with the sprint (or is not going to be fixed in the sprint) then it gets a bug created that will need to be prioritized by the product owner.  It took some getting used to, but now that we do it, I find it really nice.  It allows us to have bugs be something that need to be prioritized and worked into the schedule.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I like the idea of treating "product bugs" different from the usual workflow, ensuring they are triaged alongside the rest of the non-sprint backlog instead of being either forgotten or mindlessly driven to 0.  What I can't fathom is the lack of a mechanism for tracking "in progress" tasks more granularly.  If I find 10 bugs in a new feature, my options become (1) cram them into that task & hope nothing gets overlooked (2) start an email thread (3) refer to some other collaboration tool like OneNote or Sharepoint.  All of them seem to defeat the purpose of owning TFS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for an online Whiteboard you can have a look at the Scrum tool [Agilo](http://www.agile42.com/cms/pages/agilo/). It was build especially for distributed teams which do not have the chance to work on a  "real" whiteboard. 
For a quick information you can have a look at this [video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=un6waqaiIJ0)

Answer (score 1):

The 3.0 version of the template for VS 2010 changes how the tool models Scrum in ways to very effectively support multi-team projects and the typical interactions one will find in larger projects.

Regardless of version, it is currently my default answer for Scrum projects in Microsoft environments.  As mentioned, the task board and the (new) ScrumMaster's workbench are incredibly valuable as well!

Answer (score 1):

We build Urban Turtle that extend the Microsoft ALM platform with an intuitive Web interface and simplify your agile project management. By providing a Task Board and a planning board directly in web access you don't have to synchronize anything. The installation is a simple process. 2 minutes to install on the web access server. Nothing to setup on the client desktop.

Don't take my word for cash have a look at what Brian Harry from Microsoft said about the product :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2010/10/21/urban-turtle-3-5-released.aspx

Have a look at the website and send me your feedback

urbanturtle.com

Dominic Danis
Product Owner.